# c++ sorting algorithms duration

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, time, duration

I have been working on calculating duration of these sorting algorithms take. I looped all sorting methods 2000 times then divide total duration into 2000 to get a proper value for duration. The problem is; it does not show the exact value of time that the particular code parts of sorting methods take. I mean the `duration` variable shows increasing values through the program flows. For example, for `N = 10000`, `insertionSort()`gives 0.000635, `mergeSort()`gives 0.00836 and `heapSort()` gives 0.018485 and when I change order of these, `duration` still goes up through program, regardless of algorithm type. I tried giving different duration values for each process but that didn't work. Can someone help me to understand this problem or are there any other time measuring styles?

Sorry if this is a dumb problem and for my bad grammar.

```
int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    int N, duration;

    cout << endl << "N : ";
    cin >> N; // N is array sze.
    cout << endl;

    // a4 would be the buffer array (for calculating proper duration).
    int *a1 = new int[N];
    int *a2 = new int[N];
    int *a3 = new int[N];
    int *a4 = new int[N];

    cout << endl << "Unsorted array : " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        a4[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << a4[i] << " ";
    }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    cout << endl << endl <<"Sorting with Insertion Sort, please wait..." << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){

        a1 = a4;

        duration = clock();
        insertionSort(a1, N - 1);
        duration += clock() - duration;
    }

    cout << endl << "Insertion sort : " << endl;

    print(a1, N);

    cout << endl << endl << "Approximate duration for Insertion Sort : ";
    cout << (double) (duration / 2000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << " s." << endl;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    cout << endl << endl << "Sorting with Merge Sort, please wait..." << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){

        a2 = a4;

        duration = clock();
        mergeSort(a2, 0, N - 1);
        duration += clock() - duration;
    }

    cout << endl << "Merge sort : " << endl;

    print(a2, N);

    cout << endl << endl << "Approximate duration for Merge Sort : ";
    cout << (double) (duration / 2000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << " s."<< endl << endl;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    cout << endl << endl << "Sorting with Heap Sort, please wait..." << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){

        a3 = a4;
        duration = clock();
        heapSort(a3, N);
        duration += clock() - duration;
    }

    cout << endl << "Heap sort : " << endl;

    print(a3, N);

    cout << endl << endl << "Approximate duration for Heap Sort : ";
    cout << (double) (duration / 2000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << " s."<< endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the order of the original data will also affect the sorting performance.  Not only do you need to perform the sort many times on one set of data, you will also need to perform the sort on many sets of data to get a more accurate or overall performance rating.  Also be aware that the timing may be affected by other applications running on your machine.

Answer (score 7):

The error in your program is that you reset duration throughout the loop. A cleaner way to handle the time would be to put the `duration` variable modification outside the for loop. For example:

```
duration = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
    a2 = a4;
    mergeSort(a2, 0, N - 1);
}
duration = clock() - duration
```

EDIT: forgot to remove the part inside the loop. Fixed now.

Comment: +1. This is the best solution. It includes the small loop overhead, but the alternative would involve calculating the duration of each iteration and adding that to a `total_duration` or somesuch. I suspect the call to `clock` would require more cycles than the loop overhead.

Comment: Does it make an important difference if I use `duration` inside the loop and `total_duration`outside, or @jma127 's way?

Comment: It adds a bit of extra time to the calculation that the `total_duration` method doesn't have: namely, the for loop iteration/condition check, and the pointer assignment. However, given a big enough `N` (say, 1000 or so), it will be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Number one, you don't seem to reset `duration` between runs of the different sorts.  This means the sum of individual iteration durations would be propagating down through each sorting phase (if the next point weren't also a problem).

Next, you need to setup a separate variable, call it `durationSum` and use that as you are currently using `duration` in the summary phase after iterating. Currently, you're blowing away your sum on every iteration.

For example:

```
clock_t durationSum = 0;
clock_t duration = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){

    a1 = a4;

    duration = clock();
    insertionSort(a1, N - 1);
    durationSum += clock() - duration;
}
```

Next, you're making a type error when amortizing `duration`.  You have:

```
cout << (double) (duration / 2000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

With minimal edits, this would work more precisely (but should use `durationSum`):

```
cout << (double) (duration / 2000.0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Before, you were saying "use integer division to divide `duration` by 2000, THEN promote it to a `double` and divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (this time with floating-point division because one of the operands is a `double` and one integral). Using `2000.0` forces `duration` to be promoted to a double for a floating-point division by 2000.

Finally, it would be better to consider the loop overhead negligible compared to a single sort iteration and do only two calls to clock() per 2000 sort-iterations.

For example:

```
clock_t insert_sort_start = clock();

for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
    a1 = a4;
    insertionSort(a1, N - 1);
}

double duration_sec = (clock() - insert_sort_start) / 2000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Finally, note that you are using `duration` as an `int` whereas in reality it is a `clock_t`, and if you are on a 64-bit system, it is very likely that this is a 64-bit number being returned by `clock()` and "narrowed" (downcast) into a 32-bit integer `int`. Use `clock_t`.

Comment: Also, a nit unrelated to your direct question: why are you allocating `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`?  As you're currently using them, you just reassign them to point at `a4` (and lose the reference to their allocated memory, leaking).  You can just declare them as `int*` and not initialize them with `new`.

Comment: Thanks for all these tips. I still suffer from being a rookie :)